# Regex matching punctuation and roman in lowercase

Tags: java, regex, roman-numerals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Hi,

How do I match regex to something like

```
[i])
[ii])
[iii])
[iv])
```

and so on...

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the square brackets are a part of what I want to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^\[[ivmcldx]+\])/
```

should catch the most common roman numerals. It won't stumble on invalid numerals like `iiix`, though.

Comment: The `)` will need to be escaped though.