# Match Roman Numeral

Tags: php, regex, roman-numerals

Looking to validate/Match [Roman Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals), are there any libraries or functions that can do this?

Would a RegEx work?

Not sure about how to go about this, any thoughts? suggestions?

I did see this PEAR package: [Numbers Roman](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Roman/redirected) but looks like it's not actively being updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex solution:

[How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

> - [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)