# Collection Order by Roman Numeral

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a Database with Budapest Districts in it i.e

- I.
- II.
- V.
- IV.
- IX.

These are strings in my Database.

If I was to order by their column "region". The order is wrong.

Is there any way I can order a Laravel Collection or even write a custom "order by" for either the collection or the Database search to order by the roman numeral equivalent?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, store the `integer` equivalent alongside these and order by that. As you said, these are `string`s, and will sort alphabetically (which is obviously not the correct order for Roman Numerals).

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Thanks @TimLewis

Comment: No problem! I feel like that will be the quickest/easiest solution, unless you can find some kind of PHP/SQL package for translating roman numerals to their int equivalent. Might be an interesting problem to try and solve though :)

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for that, so solution was created a "district_numeric" column in Database. Which takes a numeric value from a PHP function that converts the string to an integer i.e V = 5. Then order by that column, works a treat

Comment: Nice, and is likely much faster than trying to order by with a custom function; I'm sure the conversion is pretty quick for only a few records, but that would grind to a halt for large DB tables. Feel free to add your approach as an answer and accept it (when the system allows) to properly close this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

by default, Laravel collection has a method called `orderBy` which accepts a column name. see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-sortby

Another thing you mentioned for writing your custom `order` function can be done through extending collections. see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#extending-collections

And finally, another thing you need to sort roman numbers is explained in detail below: 
[How to sort an array of Roman numerals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507536/how-to-sort-an-array-of-roman-numerals)

Comment: Please don't post other answers as your own answer on Stackoverflow. If this question has already been asked and answered, add it as a comment to the original question or vote to close as a duplicate.