# Sort roman number in php

Tags: php, roman-numerals

I have a classes in roman number like

```
    I
    II 
    III
    IV
    IX
    V
    VI
    VII
    XI Commerce
    XI Arts 
    XI Science
```

i have tried sorting by roman number function but due to extra string are there with XI class like arts, commerce so its now working as per aspected. Is there any way to come out with any result.

[image]

Comment: Better you make converter function the roman to numeric first ..

Comment: I have already tried this but the extra string with the number cause the issue

Comment: This might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265596/how-to-convert-a-roman-numeral-to-integer-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a sorf field or something where would be

```
id value
1    I
2    II
3    III
```

and so on

Comment: I am looking for any php method

Comment: `$a = array('XIX', 'LII', 'V', 'MCCXCIV', 'III', 'XIII');

$bool = usort($a, function($a, $b) {
    return RomanNumber::Roman2Int($a) - RomanNumber::Roman2Int($b);
});    
var_dump($a);` try this. maybe it would help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265596/how-to-convert-a-roman-numeral-to-integer-in-php/6291089#6291089

Comment: You have a class that already has the roman numbers inside it? or you drag those numbers out of database?

Comment: Admin can add new classes and its coming from db

Answer (score 1):

explode string first to get the roman numerals.

```
$str = explode(" ",$yourstring);
$roman = $str[0]; //the roman numerals
$subject = $str[1]; //the subject;
```

then make a function to convert roman numerals to numbers.