# Matching Roman Numbers

Tags: php, regex, roman-numerals

I have regular expression

```
(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}|M{1,4}|CM|CD|D?C{1,3}|XC|XL|L?X{1,3})
```

I use it to detect if there is any roman number in text.

```
eregi("( IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.]| M{1,4}[\.]| CM|CD|D?C{1,3}[\.]| XC|XL|L?X{1,3}[\.])", $title, $regs)
```

But format of roman number is always like this: " IV."... I have added in eregi example white space before number and "." after number but I still get the same result. If text is something like "somethinvianyyhing" the result will be vi (between both)...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no space before `VI` the space belongs always to the alternative before it was written and not to all. The same for the `\.` it belongs always to the alternative where it was written.

Try this

```
" (IX|IV|V?I{0,3}|M{1,4}|CM|CD|D?C{1,3}|XC|XL|L?X{1,3})\."
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ug2b)

This will match

I.
 II.
 III.
 IV.
 V.
 VI.
 VII.
 VIII.
 IX.
 X.

But not

XI.
 MMI.
 MMXI.
somethinvianyyhing

**Your approach to match roman numbers is far from being correct**, an approach to match the roman numbers more correct is this, for numbers till 50 (L)

```
^(?:XL|L|L?(?:IX|X{1,3}|X{0,3}(?:IX|IV|V|V?I{1,3})))$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uhln)

I tested this only on the surface, but you see this will really get complex and in this expression C, D and M are still missing.

Not to speak about special cases for example 4 = IV = IIII and there are more of them.

[Wikipedia about Roman numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)

Comment: Also on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: There is a Perl module that handles Roman numerals correctly.  The way to know you have one is to *first* match `/\b([ivxldcm]+)\b/i` and *then* check whether `Roman::isroman($1)` returns true. Otherwise you get wrong answers. It only works on ASCII, which means it only goes up to 4000. The longest such legal string is `MMMDCCCLXXXVIII`.  With Unicode, you can go much much higher, since you have the bigger Roman numerals like ↂ for 10,000 *&c* — and you also have the macron or overline for a 1000 times the base char. I have a module that handles all these, but it is of course written in Perl.☺