# How to use Pattern to check if a string matches any numerals in I, II, III, IV, V

Tags: java, regex, arrays

If I have a string a = I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII

How can I use pattern to check if my input string matches any of these roman numbers?

Or is there any easier way to do so?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967896/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals-java

Comment: Is this question any different than looking up `"ab"`, in `["a", "ab", "aba"]`? Please clarify.

Comment: If you literally need to match against only 7 possible strings, you don't really need regular expressions. Just brute force it. For example, you could try something like `Arrays.asList("I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII").contains(a)`.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. About matching roman numbers see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104623/matching-roman-numbers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Leesei, basically my goal is to use pattern to check if an input string, let's say a, is equal to any of the roman numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String pattern="^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$";

    String input="VIII";
    if(input.matches(pattern)){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

[How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression/267405#267405)

Comment: This is the same regex than [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/626273). There you can also find an explanation. It would be nice if you give credits to that answerer, if you reuse his solution. Btw. in Java you can omit the anchors `^` and `$`, `matches()` is always matching against the whole input.

Comment: thanks alot Prabhakaran!
Btw how do you come up with the pattern string?