# Convert a string containing a roman numeral to integer equivalent

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
str = "MMX Lions Television Inc"
```

And I need to convert it into:

```
conv_str = "2010 Lions Television Inc"
```

I have the following function to convert a roman numeral into its integer equivalent:

```
numeral_map = zip(
    (1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1),
    ('M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I')
)

def roman_to_int(n):
    n = unicode(n).upper()

    i = result = 0
    for integer, numeral in numeral_map:
        while n[i:i + len(numeral)] == numeral:
            result += integer
            i += len(numeral)
    return result
```

How would I use `re.sub` to do the get the correct string here?

(Note: I tried using the `regex` described here: [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression) but it was not working.)

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a straight-up dictionary for holding your roman numerals, and then using the keys to get the value?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, because the order in which the numerals are extracted is relevant. `1000` must be `M` - it can't be `DD` or `CCCCCCCCCC` which you'd get if you used a dictionary. At least for conversions from decimal to roman numerals, you need the fixed order of numerals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub()` can accept a function as the replacement, the function will receive a single argument which is the Match object, and should return a replacement string.  You already have a function to convert a Roman numeral string to an int so this won't be difficult.

In your case you would want a function like this:

```
def roman_to_int_repl(match):
    return str(roman_to_int(match.group(0)))
```

Now you can modify the regex from the question you linked so that it will find matches within a larger string:

```
s = "MMX Lions Television Inc"
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?=[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b')
print regex.sub(roman_to_int_repl, s)
```

Here is a version of the regex that would not replace "LLC" in a string:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?!LLC)(?=[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b')
```

You could also use the original regex with a modified replacement function:

```
def roman_to_int_repl(match):
    exclude = set(["LLC"])   # add any other strings you don't want to replace
    if match.group(0) in exclude:
        return match.group(0)
    return str(roman_to_int(match.group(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. How would you also get the `re` to ignore "LLC"?

Comment: At the beginning of the regex, add the following `(?!LLC\b)`, if is a larger list that you want to disallow, you can use something like the following: `(?!(LLC|XXX|I)\b)`

Answer (score 7):

Always try the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) when looking for a common function/library.

This is the [list of modules related to the keyword 'roman'](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=roman&submit=search).

For example 'romanclass' has a class that implement the conversion, quoting the documentation:

```
So a programmer can say:

>>> import romanclass as roman

>>> two = roman.Roman(2)

>>> five = roman.Roman('V')

>>> print (two+five)

and the computer will print:

VII
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would this be applied to the problem above?

Comment: At a guess: extract the Roman numeral from the string using regex (as per the other answer you linked in the OP), then use this module to convert your Roman numeral to a number. Use regex for what it's good at (finding strings) and this Roman module for what it's good at (converting strings to numbers) and you will have a robust solution.