# Using regex to change roman numerals to integers

Tags: python, regex, string-conversion, roman-numerals

I just started toying around with regex. I've looked at [Google's Python regex howto](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?csw=1) and [Python's regex howto](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html) as well as other similar questions like [Convert a string containing a roman numeral to integer equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093618/convert-a-string-containing-a-roman-numeral-to-integer-equivalent) and [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression), but I am still confused.

My code:

```
user = str(input("Input the Roman numeral: "))
characters = "I", "V" "X", "L", "C", "D", "M"
values = 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000

def numerals(match):
    return str(user(match.group(0)))

s = str(input("Input the Roman numeral: "))
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?=[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?    I{0,3})\b')
print regex.sub(numerals, s)
```

The last two lines are from the first link.  I don't fully understand `regex = re.compiler...` and am wondering if it actually converts the user's roman numerals to integers?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't. IDLE's subprocess won't connect for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code. First, your regular expression is finding unecessary matches. When using parenthesis, use non matching expression `(?:` to avoid finding partial matches. The line

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?=[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b')
```

create a expression to find Roman numbers inside a text. This is only useful if you are going to use this expression frequently (like in a for loop). If you are going to use once, you can don't need to compile before using it. The following line requesting the user input again, because the function `numerals` calls the function `user`. So it requests the same user input twice. And finally, it tries to replace the first user input with the second one.

```
print regex.sub(numerals, s)
```

Converting from Romans to Decimals is a complex task and would probably require an algorithm. I make a few changes in your code just to point it in the right direction:

```
import re
text = input("Input the Roman numeral: ")
matches = re.findall(r'(?=\b[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})', text)
for match in matches:
    print('Match: {}'.format(match))
```

Output:

```
Input a phrase with some Roman numerals: I LIVE IN III PLACES
Match: I
Match: III
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, they want to convert roman to integer.