# How to catch roman numbers inside string?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to catch roman numbers inside string (numbers below 80 is fine enough). I found good base for it in [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression). Problem is: it deals with whole strings. I did not found yet a solution how to detect roman numbers inside string, because there is nothing mandatory, every group may be optional. So far i tried something like this:

```
my $x = ' some text I-LXIII iv more ';

if (  $x =~  s/\b(
                    (
                        (XC|XL|L?X{0,3}) # first group 10-90
                    |
                        (IX|IV|V?I{0,3}) # second group 1-9
                    )+
            )
        \b/>$1</xgi ) { # mark every occurrence
    say $x;
}

__END__
 ><some>< ><text>< ><>I<><-><>LXIII<>< ><>iv<>< ><more>< 
 desired output:
  some text >I<->LXIII< >iv< more
```

So, this one captures word boundaries by themself too, because all groups are optional. How to get it done? How to make one of those 2 groups mandatory while there is no possible to tell which one is mandatory? Other approaches to catch romans are welcome too.

Comment: Generally, to say `a` or `b` or `ab`, but not nothing, you can do `(a|b|ab)` or `(ab?|b)`, but you will not get around duplication.

Comment: Problem: `a` or `b` themself consist of 4 optional blocks. To cover all those combinations seems pretty crazy.

Comment: Ah right, I see your point. Does Perl support look aheads? You could add a lookahead to beginning of the match (after the boundary): `(?=[IVXLDCM])`

Comment: If i have any word beginning with those letters, those boundaries will captured too. Or i did wrong way, not too familiar with lookaheads. Maybe you could try regex and present your code as answer too?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the first thing about Perl (which is why I posted the suggestion only as a comment). However, looking at your regex again, I think the only problem is, that `L?X{0,3}` and it's counterpart can be empty. Expand these to `L?X{1,3}|L` and `V?I{1,3}|V`. Then the `+` at the end should make sure that you don't get empty strings between boundaries.

Comment: `X` or `I` can't be mandatory, setting them `{1,3}` makes them mandatory. My questions is not very Perl-related, general regex solution will work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Perl lets us down with its missing `\<` and `\>` (beginning and end word boundary) constructs that are available elsewhere. A pattern like `\b...\b` will match even if the `...` consumes none of the target string because the second `\b` will happily match the *beginning* word boundary a second time.

However an end word boundary is just `(?<=\w)(?!\w)` so we can use this instead.

This program will do what you want. It does a look-ahead for a string of potential Roman characters enclosed in word boundaries (so we must be at a *beginning* word boundary) and then checks for a *legal* Roman number that isn't followed by a word character (so now we're at an *end* word boundary).

Note that I've reversed your `>...<` marks as they were confusing me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $x = ' some text I-LXIII iv more ';

if ( $x =~ s{
    (?= \b [CLXVI]+ \b )
    (
      (?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})?
      (?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})?
    )
    (?!\w)
    }
    {<$1>}xgi ) {

    say $x;
}
```

**output**

```
some text <I>-<LXIII> <iv> more
```

Comment: You use in code `(?!\w)` as end boundary, but earlier you define it as `(?<=\w)(?!\w)`. Is this just a typo or i miss something here?

Comment: @w.k: What we're doing is finding a string of *word* characters made up entirely of the Roman letters, and then making sure it is a valid Roman number. The `(?!\w)` is there to make sure that *all* of this string is a valid Roman number instead of just the first few characters. If we had `LXIC`, for instance, then only `LXI` would be valid, and `(?!\w)` wouldn't match because `C` is a word character. Adding `(?<=\w)` only serves to prevent the boundary between two non-word characters also matching, and that never occurs here

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Roman](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Roman-1.23/lib/Roman.pm) CPAN module

```
use Roman;

my $x = ' some text I-LXIII VII XCVI IIIXII iv more ';
if (  $x =~  
    s/\b
    (
        [IVXLC]+
    )
    \b
    /isroman($1) ? ">$1<" : $1/exgi ) {
    say $x;
}
```

**output:**

```
some text >I<->LXIII< >VII< >XCVI< IIIXII >iv< more
```

Comment: Thank you, but it captures also non valid sequences.