# jquery roman numeral with maskedinput

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

Help me with masked input mask for roman numeral. I need to create a mask with which I can input only roman number from I to X

Comment: Do you have a plugin for validation?

Comment: In this case, it's probably easiest to test against all ten valid values.

Comment: thanks, dropdown is the best way!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a plugin, the easiest way is to write a regex and match an input value against it.
If found a really really nice one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

```
$(function(){
    var strInput = $('input#myRomanInputField').val();
    var matchArr = strInput.match(/^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/g);
    console.log(matchArr);
    if(matchArr) {
        // test successful
        console.log("true");
    } else {
        // failure
        console.log("false");
    }
});
```

For numbers 1-10, just use this regex:

```
/^(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$|^X$/g
```