# regex for roman numberal not working

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to identify roman numberals from text with the following regex:

```
>>>Title="LXXXIV XC, XCII      XXX     LXII"
>>>RomanNum = re.findall(r'[\s,]+M{0,4}[CM|CD|D?C{0,3}]?[XC|XL|L?X{0,3}]?[IX|IV|V?I{0,3}]?[\s,]+', Title, re.M|re.I)`
>>>RomanNum
[' \t']
```

I want something like:

```
['LXXXIV', 'XC, 'XCII', 'XXX', 'LXII']
```

As far as my understanding of regular expression is concerned I think at least `XC` should have been matched. `XC` should match `[XC|XL|L?X{0,3}]` part of regular expression above with whitespace before and a comma after it which is captured by the above regex. What am I missing?

Apart from that I can achieve the desired result as following(but greater complexity which I want to avoid):

```
>>>RomanNum = [re.search(r'^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$', TitleElem, re.M|re.I) for TitleElem in re.split(',| ', Title)]`
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `[IVXLCDM]+`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe They would not form a valid roman numeral

Comment: And have you tried any of the other regexes for matching Roman numerals (e.g. see the Related questions in the right-hand sidebar)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I took the regex from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression. Understood it. Tried to modify it for my own use. Does not work(which means I didn't understood properly and hence the question)

Comment: So what exactly is the difference between what that regex does and what you want? The answer provides a step-by-step explanation of how it works - what is the issue?

Comment: For what strange reason do you change parenthesis to brackets?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte realized the mistake now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want it to match anywhere in the string(sentence) and hence instead of `^` and `$` markers need to word boundaries(`\b`) which does not seem to work. So while this expression(copied from other answer):`^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$` works  this: `\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex syntax is off at this point:

> `XC` should match `[XC|XL|L?X{0,3}]`

because you use *square* brackets, where you describe the behavior of *round* parentheses. Change the square brackets to round ones to correct.

This error is repeated in other parts of your full regex.

Comment: `RomanNum = re.findall(r'[\s,]+M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[\s,]+', Title, re.M|re.I)` does not give `XCII` as an output.

Comment: Also how can we modify it to break at spaces, puntuations etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find several roman numbers in a string with the `findall` or `finditer` method, one possible pattern is:

```
(?=[MDCXLVI])(?<![MDCXLVI])M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})(?![MDCXLVI])
```

It's a bit long and I will explain why I think it is efficient:

`(?=[MDCXLVI])` is a lookahead that checks if the position is followed by one of these characters. This lookahead has two functions:

- The first is to emulate a kind of *first-character discrimination* to quickly avoid all positions that don't contain one of these characters (In this way, the regex engine don't need to test all possible beginings with `M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})`).
- The second checks if there is at least one character, since `M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})` can match an empty string.

`(?<![MDCXVLI])` and `(?![MDCXVLI])` are used as boundaries to ensure there are no other "roman characters" around (otherwise a substring like `ILVIII` will return `LVIII` as result instead of skipping the entire group of characters with a wrong format). *Note that other kind of boundaries are possible, like `\b` or `(?<![^\s,])` `(?![^\s,])` ... depending of the string format.* Note too, that the left boundary is placed only after `(?=[MDCXVLI])` to not break the first-character discrimination.

Alternations like `CM|CD` are reduced to `C[MD]`.

The pattern use only non-capturing groups `(?:...)` to preserve memory and avoid uneeded storage tasks.

Comment: For `string="XXXII, LXIII LXV     LXVII ABC RAM, ED"` the following: `re.findall('(?:\b)M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})(?:\b)', string)` return `[]`. Why?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: because when you don't use a raw string (i.e. `r'....'`), all the backslashes must be escaped: `re.findall('(?=[MDCXLVI])\\bM{0,4...\\b', string)` or `re.findall(r'(?=[MDCXLVI])\bM{0,4...\b', string)`. As an aside, you don't need to put `\b` in a group.

Answer (score 0):

[Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/roman_numerals.html) provides a nice regex for detecting Roman Numerals. They also provide a [sample script](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/utils/roman.py) that you can utilize to start. This script comes from section [7.5](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/verbose.html) of my first link.

```
#Define pattern to detect valid Roman numerals
romanNumeralPattern = re.compile("""
    ^                   # beginning of string
    M{0,4}              # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
    (CM|CD|D?C{0,3})    # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
                        #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
    (XC|XL|L?X{0,3})    # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
                        #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
    (IX|IV|V?I{0,3})    # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
                        #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
    $                   # end of string
    """ ,re.VERBOSE)
```