# Valid roman numerals mask for textbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, roman-numerals

How to forbid user to type not valid roman numerals on input stage in textbox.
For example:
VV or IXI are not valid roman numerals, 
so I want to develop functional that would not allow user to type V after V or I after IX.
I have tried this (meioMask plugin):

```
  function addMasks() {
      jQuery.mask.rules = {
                  'A': /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/,  
                  $('#<%=tbSeries.ClientID%>').setMask('AAAAAAA');       
      };
```

but this mask working only for each symbol, but not for whole number.

Comment: Which mask plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry I don't even know, just supporting an old project. That function was already written by previous developer.

Comment: So find out. Look in included JS files - there is likely a copyright message

Comment: With the files you posted. It appears to be this one: https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask

Comment: `^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/267405 http://www.regexr.com/3a406

Comment: jquery.meio.mask.js included, it's probably meioMask plugin

Answer (score 0):

The regex is correct, but it looks like the meioMask code is not right.

Try this:

```
$.mask.masks.roman = {mask: 'M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})'};
$('#<%=tbSeries.ClientID%>').setMask('roman');
```

The regex covers the entire numeral, not each digit. So use the regex as the complete mask (not repeated like `AAAAAAA`).