# Extract all numbers and roman numerals from a div tag

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup, extract

I'm using Java and Jsoup to extract the content of the `div` tag. I need to extract only the numbers.

```
String html = "";
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements divs = document.select("div");
    for (Element div : divs) {
        System.out.println(div.ownText());
    }
```

and the output is something like this

```
Adidas, 45-46 Nike, 25 shoes, phone, keyboard, 1–2, 4–5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 32, 35,
```

My problem is how can I extract the number content of the `div` tag? Each number has a comma before the needs. So how can I do it using regex? Thank you

**Update:** How can I extract the number and Roman numeral?

```
Adidas, 45-46 Nike, 25 shoes, phone, keyboard, 1–2, 4–5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 32, 35, V, VI, IX,
```

This post is not the same question with the link above because my problem needs to extract Roman numerals

Comment: Number content means? all the numbers? i.e. `45, 46, 25` etc

Comment: What is the desired result? E.g. do you want `45-46` as one "number" or `45` and `46` separated?

Comment: yes all numbers, even the 45-46. my desired result is 45-46 as one number not 45, 46. thank you

Comment: and what do you want from `25 shoes`?

Comment: no @rock321987 just the numbers only, thank you.

Comment: you mean [this](http://ideone.com/aCcd1N)

Comment: @rock321987 that's what i needed. thank you

Comment: @rock321987 i have another question sir. how can i extract the text and the roman numeral? you're code for extracting number are great but i forgot to mention i also need to extract the roman numeral. thank you

Comment: is there be possibility of - `VI-10`?

Comment: An exact sample of expected result from the sample string will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This Regex will do the following:

- Match all numeric strings like 2, 3977, 432, 5 ..
- Match all Ranges of numeric strings like 2-4, 553-999, 1234-9876
- Match all valid Roman Numerals in the range of 1-4000
- returns an array of only these values and no additional capture groups

**The Regex**

```
\b(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?|(?=[MCDLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\b
```

Note this is just a raw regex, for many languages like Java you'll need to replace the `\` with `\\` to get it to work correctly.

## Explanation

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [MCDLXVI]+               any character of: 'M', 'C', 'D', 'L',
                               'X', 'V', 'I' (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    M{0,4}                   'M' (between 0 and 4 times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      CM                       'CM'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      CD                       'CD'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      D?                       'D' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      C{0,3}                   'C' (between 0 and 3 times (matching
                               the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      XC                       'XC'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      XL                       'XL'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      L?                       'L' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      X{0,3}                   'X' (between 0 and 3 times (matching
                               the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      IX                       'IX'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      IV                       'IV'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      V?                       'V' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      I{0,3}                   'I' (between 0 and 3 times (matching
                               the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Examples

**Live Demo**

http://fiddle.re/pvjzra

**Sample Text**

```
Adidas, 45-46 Nike, 25 shoes, phone, keyboard, 1-2, 4-5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 32, 35, V, VI, IX
```

**Java Code Example**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "Adidas, 45-46 Nike, 25 shoes, phone, keyboard, 1-2, 4-5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 32, 35, V, VI, IX";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:\\d+(?:-\\d+)?|(?=[MCDLXVI]+\\b)M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Matched Array**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45-46
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 1-2
            [3] => 4-5
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 9
            [6] => 12
            [7] => 13
            [8] => 32
            [9] => 35
            [10] => V
            [11] => VI
            [12] => IX
        )

)
```

Comment: i tried running you're code but it gives me wrong output sir. it removes the hypen for 1-2 and 4-5  [0][0] = 45-46
[1][0] = 25
[2][0] = 1
[3][0] = 2
[4][0] = 4
[5][0] = 5
[6][0] = 7
[7][0] = 9
[8][0] = 12
[9][0] = 13
[10][0] = 32
[11][0] = 35
[12][0] = V
[13][0] = VI
[14][0] = IX

Comment: @audreyruaburo, this is happening because the hyphen as included in the string, looks like a hyphen but is subtlety different. I reran this and saw my instance of java having a hard time parsing it.  I'll update my answer and replace the odd hyphens `–` with real hyphens `-`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex:

`\b(\d+(-\d+)?|(M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3})))\b`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/rW1mY1/3

### Explanation:

1. `\b` for word boundary.
2. `(M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3}))` That is Roman numeral validator. I got it from here: [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression#answer-10441405)
3. `\d+(-\d+)?` matches digit with optional number range

Comment: how can i apply it on java?

i tried but it doesn't work as expected
String pattern = "\\b(\\d+(-\\d+)?|(M{1,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|C?D|D?C{1,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|X?L|L?X{1,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|I?V|V?I{1,3})))\\b";