# How do you match valid integers and roman numerals with a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a very helpful article on how to validate roman numerals [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression/5326535)

Regex has always been my achilles heel in spite of all my efforts. How do I expand the regular expression provided to match `normal` integers as well? The provided regular expression is:

```
/^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$/
```

Comment: Can you further explain what sorts of input should pass validation?  Can an arabic numeral appear inside a roman numeral?  If not, then @Wiktor 's comment should do the trick.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: not quite a good duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I know where I say 'normal' integers may mean different things to different people... in my case I just meant 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It doesn't show how the regex alternation works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: for you, maybe. But maybe not for the OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Respectly, I beg to differ. Based on the answer given, `(new RegExp('^\d+$/')).test('XI');` will return false

Comment: @JohnGathogo: It's fine for that example (although have an extra `/` in it), but in general, don't use `new RegExp` when dealing with a constant expression. Use `/.../` notation, so you don't have to worry about two layers of backslashes. (Also, not quite sure what you're saying there, Wiktor didn't suggest `/^\d+$/`.)

Comment: @Crowder: Thanks for the advice. Wiktor did say its a perfect dupe. If it was, I'd think the answer given there would be a fit for this case. I was just trying to demonstrate that its not.

Comment: Actually, I missed that it has `\d` in a string, so the ``\`` will be completely ignored.

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Ah, sorry, I hadn't followed the conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you just want *decimal* integers in regular form (e.g., `1000` would be valid, `1e3` [the same number in scientific notation] would not), the regular expression to validate that is `\d+`, which means "one or more digit(s)."

To have your regular expression allow that, you'd want an *alternation*, which lets either of two alternatives match. Alternations are in the form `first|second` where `first` and `second` are the alternatives.

Since your current expression has "beginning" and "end" of input assertions (`^` and `$`), we'd either want to include those in the second alternative as well, or put the entire alternation in a non-capturing group.

So either:

```
    /^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$|^\d+$/
// Note -----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

([on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qY6xD9/2))

or

```
    /^(?:M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|\d+)$/
//    ^^^                                                      ^^^^^
```

([on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL2qP9/1))

Note that your original expression has a few capture groups (but doesn't entirely consist of captures); if you wanted to *capture* the `\d+` part, you'd put `()` around it.

Comment: @Crowder: I know integers may mean different things to different people... in my case I just meant 1, 2, 3,...

Comment: @JohnGathogo: Just framing the problem in order to solve it. Sometimes people want to handle scientific notation as well, which complicates things a bit.

Comment: @Crowder: I understand. My challenge has always been in combining two or more regex expressions in such a way that the combined expression has the expected outcome. That is what I never seem to master.