# JavaScript Sort Alphanumeric Floats

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort questions by their numbers. The numbers may include spaces or dots as spacers. So a sorted set may look like the following:

`'1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.2.a', '1.2 a', '1.2.b', '1.2.c', '1.5', '1.2a', '2', '3', '20'`

I guess  the first thing would be to replace all spaces with dots and then sort the set as a floating point integers whereby a, b, c... comes after 7, 8, 9

Comment: what is 1.2a ? ?

Comment: I'd probably replace all the spaces with dots, split it, then do a localeCompare since you have letters as well

Comment: what means ***float*** in the question?

Comment: really '1.2a' after '1.5' ?

Comment: *Codes?* Same question mate. Please share your attempt.

Comment: @Mahi Yes its 1.21

Comment: @vassiliskrikonis yes

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings

Comment: @Rajesh i am working on something

Comment: This kind of solves it. There is a slight difference in sort order but I can prevent spaces using validation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150011/sort-array-of-objects-with-dots-letters-numbers-i-was-able-to-sort-by-numbers

Comment: I can't answer anymore, anyway I was already writing my solution, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha2e7enj/) please, I hope it helps you. Bye