# how to find if a record has roman numerals in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008, roman-numerals

I want to detect records from a table (SQL Server) if it has roman numerals.

Table has data as follows:

```
    Column A | Column B
-----------------------------
1            | AMC I XYZAQS
2            | ABC IV 2 XYZQWS
3            | ANR XVI ANCVP
4            | SWD POL 2#
```

So, the result will be the first 3 records

Comment: How would you know if a character is a roman numeral? The 4th record in your sample has an `L` which is a roman numeral as well, why don't you want it selected?

Comment: And what's the surrounding language? Is `LIV` roman numerals or just the word "life" in Swedish?

Comment: I will consider that to be a roman numeral irrespective of the fact that it has real meaning in any other language.

Comment: look here <https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24362768/Querying-for-Roman-Numerals.html#answer24257112-20>. may be this can help you

Comment: The functions are not recognized in SQL Server. Functions such as DECODE, REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: SQL server doesn't have native regex support, you'll have to write it out yourself

Comment: @RobinMackenzie: This is not specific to SQL Server. RegEx of this sort is not recognized in MS SQL Server

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Yes, that's what I am looking for

Comment: Create a table with all roman numerals, and join it using `like` would be an option. Won't perform very well, I think.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: Thanks. That's the last resort. I'm here looking out if anyone can suggest any better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(A INT,B VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
 (1,'AMC I XYZAQS')
,(2,'ABC IV 2 XYZQWS')
,(3,'ANR XVI ANCVP')
,(4,'SWD POL 2#');

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT A
          ,B
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT B AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) InParts
    FROM @dummy
)
,Splitted AS
(
    SELECT A
          ,B
          ,x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS part 
    FROM Casted
    OUTER APPLY InParts.nodes('x') AS Parts(x)
)
SELECT * FROM Splitted
WHERE UPPER(part) NOT LIKE '%[0-9ABEFGHJKNOPQRSTUWYZ]%'
```

The result

```
A   B               part
1   AMC I XYZAQS    I
2   ABC IV 2 XYZQWS IV
3   ANR XVI ANCVP   XVI
```

This will not check any rules of roman numerals. It only checks for the existance of special characters

Comment: Nice approach, but the result also includes invalid sequences of numerals, such as 'ixv'

Comment: @devio. That is my last line :-) Well, checking for such rules *with T-SQL* is cutting a bread with a chain saw...

Comment: @devio - I applied a udf to convert those "Part"s to decimal number system and ignored whenever the function did not return valid numeric value. This way we can filter the result one step ahead.