# JS/RegEx: Split string into words but using exception regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to split up a string into single words, but there are some cases which should not be splitted.

```
An example for type I string
An example for degree II string
```

So every `type` | `degree` + `I` | `II` | `III` | `IV` | `V` should be kept as a string

The result of the example strings should be

```
['An', 'example', 'for', 'type I', 'string']
['An', 'example', 'for', 'degree II', 'string']
```

In my regex I have to search for `type` or `degree`, followed by space, followed by a string with characters `I` or `V` with maximum length of 3.
Those matches should not be splited.

```
consr regex = '/(type|degree)\s(I{1,3}|V{1})/' // <-- regEx is wrong as it is not working
const result = string.split(' ')
```

I'm not quite sure how to use the regex in combination with splitting in a way, that all matches are exceptions for splitting by space character.

Comment: `(I{1,3}|V{1})` means *“either (from one to three `I`) or (exactly one `V`)”*

Comment: You might want to support all Roman numbers - [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFlHbD/2) (I shortened [this Roman number regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression) a bit).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex is great. Could you provide an answer how to use this with `split()`?

Comment: Wrap with `(...)`. See https://jsfiddle.net/fu63Lyz5/. I think you will also need to match that as whole words, hence, I added `\b` in the demo.

Comment: Thanks. But please have a look at the example shown in the post. I need all words splitted - the regex should match to the exceptions, which should not be splitted by itself. Your JsFiddle gives an array with three items...

Comment: Then why split? Match! https://jsfiddle.net/fu63Lyz5/1/ / https://regex101.com/r/VFlHbD/4

Comment: Oh... Äh... yes, that was what I wanted to say :-) Please post it as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match the words `type` and `degree` followed with any Roman number or any 1+ non-whitespace chars with

```js
var s = "An example for degree II string";
var rx = /\b(?:type|degree)\s+M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})\b|\S+/g;
console.log(s.match(rx));
```

I borrowed and shortened the [Roman number regex from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression). The pattern matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:type|degree)` - a non-capturing group matching either `type` or `degree` substrings
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})` - the [Roman number regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary (this will make sure at least 1 Roman number is present)
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars.

**Note** that in case any symbol or punctuation char is present in front  of the `degree` or `type` words, it will be matched with `\S+` branch, so you need to handle those cases before applying this regex.

Comment: Only for better understanding, as regexes are still hard for me: If I only want to keep matched strings with minimum length of 3 characters, where do I have to add this?

Comment: @user3142695: Perhaps, `\S{3,}` instead of `\S+`.