# Replace greedy elements with the appropriate

Tags: python, regex

I have such a following list:

```
import re
l = ['Part I,   Where I’M Coming From',
 'Part Ii,  Life Principles',
 'Part Iii, Work Principles']
```

I want a result,

```
l = ['Part I,   Where I’M Coming From',
     'Part II,  Life Principles',
     'Part III, Work Principles']
```

I tried:

```
In [19]: [re.sub(r'(?<=I)i+', 'I+', s) for s in l]
Out[19]:
['Part I,   Where I’M Coming From',
 'Part II+,  Life Principles',
 'Part II+, Work Principles']
```

It output `'Part II+, Work Principles'` not `'Part III, Work Principles'`

How to accomplish such a task?

Comment: What's the case for Part VI, Part IV, looks like?

Comment: @MenglongLi Good question, I've tried to address that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to use `re.sub` with a *callback* function. The callback handles more complicated logic beyond simple substitution. In your case, you need to match all lowercase `i`s following capital `I`s, figure out how many `i`'s there are, and replace accordingly.

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=I)(i+)', lambda x: 'I' * len(x.group()), 'Part Iii,  Work Principles')
'Part III,  Work Principles'
```

The callback is not invoked (i.e., no replacement occurs) if there was no match.

If you're interested in a deeper understanding of what happens, here's the same callback as a function, with a couple of print statements.

```
>>> def replace(m):
...     print(*[m, m.group(), len(m.group())], sep='\n')
...     return 'I' * len(m.group())
... 
>>> re.sub('(?<=I)(i+)', replace, 'Part Iii,  Work Principles')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 8), match='ii'>
ii
2
'Part III,  Work Principles'
```

You'll notice this prints out...

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 8), match='ii'>
ii
2
```

...In addition to performing the replacement. The important thing to note is that it passes a `match` object to the callback function. You can then figure out *what* was matched, and decide what to replace it with accordingly.

---

**Generalising to Arbitrary Roman Numerals**

If your function has to match *any roman numerals*, then you can [pass a pattern that finds those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression) to `re.sub`, but your callback simplifies greatly:

```
>>> p = r'\bM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b'
>>> string = 'Part viiI,  Work Principles'
>>> re.sub(p, lambda x: x.group().upper(), string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Part VIII,  Work Principles'
```

Now, all you need to do is uppercase the matched string.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to break everything down.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply use `re.split`, apply `str.upper`, and then use `str.format`:

```
import re
l = ['Part I,   Where I’M Coming From',
'Part Ii,  Life Principles',
'Part Iii, Work Principles']
new_l = [re.split('(?<=Part)\s|,\s+', i) for i in l]
final_l = ['{} {},  {}'.format(a, b.upper(), c) for a, b, c in new_l]
```

Output:

```
l = ['Part I,   Where I’M Coming From',
 'Part II,  Life Principles',
 'Part III, Work Principles']
```