# How to check if a string contains roman numerals in R?

Tags: r, regex, text-analysis, roman-numerals

I have a column for residential adresses in my dataset 'ad'. I want to check for addresses which has no numbers(including roman numerals) present. 
I'm using

```
ad$check <- grepl("[[:digit:]]",ad$address)
```

to flag out addresses with no digits present. How do I do the same with addresses that contain roman numerals?

Eg: "floor X, DLF Building- III, ABC City"

Comment: is the structure within our address column homogeneous? E.g. is it always _Floor #, Building #, City_? And are the numbers followed by commas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression?rq=1 could be helpful

Comment: No it is not homogeneous. Numbers may or may not be followed by commas. it can be "III DLF XI floor" as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a regex string.

Edit (my first answer was nonsense):

```
x <- c("floor Imaginary,  building- Momentum, ABC City", "floor X, DLF Building- III, ABC City")
# here come the regex 
grepl("\\b[I|V|X|L|C|D|M]\\b", x, ignore.case = FALSE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

To break it down:

`\\b` are word boundaries. It means roman numerals must be preceded or trailed by whitespace, punctuation or beginning/end of the string.

`[I|V|X|L|C|D|M]` the "word" we are looking for can only consist of the symbols used for roman numerals. These should be all as far as I know.

`ignore.case = FALSE` this is the standard which is normally set if you omit the option. I find it safer, however, to mention it explicitly if it is important for the operation at hand.

Use with caution, as a company called e.g., "LCD Industries" would also be flagged as roman numeral. You could combine my approach with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/5028841) to further test if the symbols are in the right order.

Please test on your data and report if it works.

Comment: as you say, it would depend on the data, but white space might be the solution here. the likelihood that the data contains a "V" that is not a roman numeral, for example, is much higher than whether it contains a " V " that is not a roman numeral.

Comment: The above check holds true for all addresses (whether they have roman numerals or not). If an address contains roman numerals, it will have preceding and trailing white space.

Comment: Fist answer was nonsense. The answer I linked was concerned with the order of the letters, not if they are in a string. New answer should work and was tested on the example you gave and one I added without roman numerals.