# Python & regex to pull out headers from a docx with roman numerals

Tags: python, regex

I have a large `docx` file that has the below interspersed throughout:

```
PART I
PART II
PART III
PART IIIA  # part 3, section A
PART IV
PART V
PART VI
PART VII
```

I'm trying to write a regex in python that will pull these out, with `re.match`, `re.findall`, or `re.search`. I can't figure out the correct regex syntax to only pull the above out - and nothing on SO or anywhere gives an example of correctly pulling out roman numerals.

Many examples on how to convert / validate, but nothing on simple regex matching. I was going off of this:

```
[PART].*\s[I]|[II]|[III]|[IIIA]|[IV]|[V]|[VI]|[VII]
```

or

```
[PART].*\s(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$
```

But that doesn't work - I'm messing up the "or" part. [Best other SO article I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @PatrickArtner clarified above

Comment: How many parts do you expect to have roughly?

Comment: @WoodyPride only the 8 mentioned above

Comment: `re.compile("PART\s[IVXLC]*")`  ?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression like for example https://regex101.com/r/yhEbuV/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters inside square brackets match just one of the listed characters, so in your case you shouldn't put `PART` inside square brackets. You also don't need `$` in the end because you're trying to match a substring in a bigger string.

Assuming your input string is stored in variable `s`, the following call to `re.findall` should return all such occurrences in a list:

```
re.findall(r'PART\s+(?=[MDCLXVI])M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})', s)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NGdyw3/2

Comment: Awesome - but how do I get it to return `PART` along with the roman numerals? I'm using `re.findall` and it only shows the roman numerals. Curious as to how the query would be edited

Comment: I see. Try using `re.findall` and change all capturing groups to non-capturing ones. I've updated my answer accordingly then.