# How to use regex for roman numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text-processing

I Have a text file in which roman numbers are some digits after that. i need to remove all the roman numbers using regex in a generic way as i have many text files

```
XXII 99-1
V-2
(i) 
(ix)
(vii)
```

```
regex for first and second ^[XIVC]\s[0-9]+\-\[0-9]+
regex for after 2nd line ^\([ixv]+\)
```

not able to match regex can any one help with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex, by replace:

```
[\D]
```

this will find you all the non-digits.
Good Luck!

Comment: when i try to use separately as mentioned code on online it worked. But, it is not working in my context