# Regex matching one or more digits or a Roman number from I to X after word with certain prefix

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match a number placed at the end of a string or maybe the middle.

The example would be:

```
"chapter some word 12 or IV" or "chapter some word 12 or IV some word"
```

the number what I want to extract is "**12**" or **IV** from the string.

I have tried to look around with `?:\w*` or `?=\w*`
but it does not work.

My regex:

```
if (preg_match('/ch\w*\s*\K(?|(?=((?<=|\s)\d+(?:\.\d+)?))|(?=([ivx]+(?![a-z]))))/i', $string, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Am I missing something with the regex? Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\bch\D*\K\d+~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/In1WzH/3)

**To match any 1+ digits or *Roman numbers from 1 to 10 (`I` to `X`)* after the word use

```
'~\bch.*?\K\b(?:\d+|VI{0,3}|I(?:[XV]|I{0,2}))\b~i'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEByKM/5)

Here, a set of alternatives is added to `\d+`: `VI{0,3}|I(?:[XV]|I{0,2})`.

**Details**

- `\b` - starting word boundary, no letter, digit  or `_` should appear  immediately to the left of the current position
- `ch` - a literal substring
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digit chars
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `VI{0,3}|I(?:[XV]|I{0,2})` - `V` and 0, 1, 2 or 3 `I`s (that is, Roman 5, 6, 7, 8), or `I` that is followed with `X` or `V` (that is, 9 and 4) or with 0 (so, Roman 1 is matched), 1 or 2 `I`s (Roman 2 and 3).

Comment: Could you do to match roman (ivx only) too? \D* make it don't match any roman number

Comment: @niznet Sorry, I think there is too little data: do you mean the Roman numbers as whole words may appear there? In between whitespace or punctuation?

Comment: @niznet Try `'~\bch.*?\K(?<!\w)(?:\d+|M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))(?!\w)~i'`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEByKM/1). Roman number regex is borrowed from [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/3832970).

Comment: Updated the question. I only need I , V , X (I until X)

Comment: @niznet From `I` to `X`: `'~\bch.*?\K\b(?:\d+|I{1,3}|IV|VI{0,3}|I?X)\b~i'`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEByKM/3).