# I am trying to write a regex to capture the name string before the comma excluding the Jr.|Sr. and Roman numbers

Tags: regex

The example names that I am trying it on are here

```
O'Kefe,Shiley
Folenza,Mitchel V
Briscoe Jr.,Sanford Ray
Andade-Alarenga,Blnca 
De La Cru,Feando
Carone,Letca Jo
O'Conor,Mole K
Daeron III,Lawence P
Randall,Jason L
Esquel Mendez,Mara D
Dinle III,Jams E
Coras Sr.,Cleybr E
Hsieh-Krnk,Caolyn E
Graves II,Theodore R
```

I am trying to capture everything before comma except the roman numbers and `Sr.`|`Jr.` suffix.
So if the name is like `Andade-Alarenga,Blnca`  I want to capture `Andade-Alarenga`, but if the name is `Briscoe Jr.,Sanford Ray` I just want `Briscoe`.

the code I have tried is here

```
^((?:(?![JjSs][rR]\.|\b(?:[IV]+))[^,]))
```

also this one - ^(?!\w+ \A[jr|sr|Jr|Sr].*)\w+| \w+ \w+|'\w+|-\w+$

[Regex101 my code with example sets][1]

https://regex101.com/r/jX5cK6/2

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP wants to avoid matching roman numerals (I, II, IV, IX,...)

Comment: Try `^(?:(?![JS]r\.|\b(?:[XVICMD]+)\b)[^,])+\b(?<!\s)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJeE8g/2).

Comment: Please specify language as different regex engines support different features.

Comment: Glad it did, I posted an answer with the details, see [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455358/3832970). Please consider accepting since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using a capturing group with a non greedy match up till the first occurrence of a comma and optionally before the comma match Jr Sr jr sr or a roman numeral.

Then match the comma itself. The value is in capture group 1.

An extended match for a roman numeral can be found for example on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression) as the character class `[XVICMD]+` is a broad match which would also allow other combinations.

```
^(\w.*?)(?: (?:[JjSs]r\.|[XVICMD]+\b))?,
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w.*?` Match a word char and 0+ times any char except a newline non greedy
- `)` close group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Match a space and start non capturing group

    - `[JjSs]r\.` Match any of the listed followed by `r.`
    - `|` Or
    - `[XVICMD]+\b` Match 1+ times any of the listed and a word boundary
  - `)` Close group
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `,` Match the comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sCWTDc/1)

Comment: The regex in the comments solves the problem without needlessly matching roman numerals, commas, and titles.

Comment: @jrook The question states `I am trying to capture everything before comma except the roman numbers and Sr.|Jr. suffix` So the capturing group matches until the comma, but only matches romal numberals or Jr Sr etc that is unwanted. The wanted value is in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your test on Regex101, I'm assuming your regex engine supports positive lookaheads (This is true for PCRE, Javascript or Python, for example)

A positive lookahead will enable you to match only what you want, without the need for capturing groups. The full match will be the string you're looking for.

`^[\w'\- ]+?(?= ?(?:\b(?:[IVXCMD]*|\w+\.)),)`

The part that matches the name is as simple as it gets:

`^[\w'\- ]+?`

All it does is match any of the characters on the list. the final `?` is there to make it *lazy*: This way, the engine will only match as few characters as it needs to.

The important part is this one:

`(?= ?(?:\b(?:[IVXCMD]*|\w+\.)),)`

It is divided in two parts by the pipe (this character: `|`) there. The first part matches roman numerals (or nothing), and the second part matches titles (Basically, anything that ends on a `.`). Finally, we need to match the comma, because of your requirement.

[Here it is on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bJeE8g/3)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a language so I used a regex in the `replaceAll()` String method of `Java`.

```
      String[] names = {
            "O'Kefe,Shiley", "Folenza,Mitchel V", "Briscoe Jr.,Sanford Ray",
            "Andade-Alarenga,Blnca", "De La Cru,Feando", "Carone,Letca Jo",
            "O'Conor,Mole K", "Daeron III,Lawence P", "Randall,Jason L",
            "Esquel Mendez,Mara D", "Dinle III,Jams E", "Coras Sr.,Cleybr E",
            "Hsieh-Krnk,Caolyn E", "Graves II,Theodore R"

      };

      for (String name : names) {
         System.out.println(name + " -> "
               + name.replaceAll("(I{1,3},|((Sr|Jr)\\.,)|,).*", ""));
      }
```

Here is a python solution using `re.sub`

```py
    import re
    names = ["O'Kefe,Shiley", "Folenza,Mitchel V", "Briscoe Jr.,Sanford Ray",
                "Andade-Alarenga,Blnca", "De La Cru,Feando", "Carone,Letca Jo",
                "O'Conor,Mole K", "Daeron III,Lawence P", "Randall,Jason L",
                "Esquel Mendez,Mara D", "Dinle III,Jams E", "Coras Sr.,Cleybr E",
                "Hsieh-Krnk,Caolyn E", "Graves II,Theodore R"]

    for name in names:   
        print(name, "->", re.sub("(I{1,3},|((Sr|Jr)\\.,)|,).*","",name))
```

Comment: Aplogies for not mentioning the language, I am implementing it in Python

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?:(?![JS]r\.|\b(?:[XVICMD]+)\b)[^,])+\b(?<!\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJeE8g/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:(?![JS]r\.|\b(?:[XVICMD]+)\b)[^,])+` - any char but `,` (`[^,]`), one or more occurrences (`+`),  that does not start a `Jr.` or `Sr.` char sequence or a whole word consisting of 1 or more `X`, `V`, `I`, `C`, `M`,`D` chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\s)` - no whitespace immediately to the left is allowed (it is  trimming the match)

Comment: That is a peculiar downvote. This is a good answer, detailed and confirmed by the OP. +1