# Get only character records from column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

**Table**:

```
create table tbl_prefix
(
    col_pre varchar
);
```

**Records**:

```
insert into tbl_prefix values
('Mr.'),('Mrs.'),('Ms.'),('Dr.'),
('Jr.'),('Sr.'),('II'),('III'),
('IV'),('V'),('VI'),('VII'),
('VIII'),('I'),('IX'),('X'),
('Officer'),('Judge'),('Master');
```

Expected output:

```
col_pre
----------
Mr.
Mrs.
Ms.
Dr.
Jr.
Sr.
Officer
Judge
Master
```

Try:

```
select *
from tbl_prefix
where col_pre ~ '[^a-zA-Z]'
```

Getting:

```
col_pre
----------
Mr.
Mrs.
Ms.
Dr.
Jr.
Sr.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean with "only character"?  Why is `VI` or `V`  not in the expected output - those are "characters" as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach here might be to match any prefix which is *not* a Roman numeral:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_prefix
WHERE col_pre !~ '^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$';
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The regex pattern used here for Roman numerals was gratefully taken from this SO question:

[How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)