# Using regex to split a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The regex I am using is `\d+-\d+`, but I'm not quite sure about how to separate the Roman numbers and how to create a new column with them.

I have this dataset:

```
Date_Title                        Date                       Copies
05-21 I. Don Quixote              1605                       252
21-20 IV. Macbeth                 1629                       987
10-12 ML. To Kill a Mockingbird   1960                       478
12 V. Invisible Man               1897                       136
```

Basically, I would like to split the "Date Title", so, when I print a row, I would get this:

```
('05-21 I', 'I', 'Don Quixote', 1605, 252)
```

Or

```
('10-12 ML', 'ML', 'To Kill a Mockingbird',1960, 478)
```

In the first place, the numbers and the roman numeral, in the second; only the Roman numeral, in the third the name, and the fourth and fifth would be the same as the dataset.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_Title':['05-21 I. Don Quixote','21-20 IV. Macbeth','10-12 ML. To Kill a Mockingbird','12 V. Invisible Man'], 'Date':[1605,1629,1960,1897], 'Copies':[252,987,478,136]})
rx = r'^(\d+(?:-\d+)?\s*(M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})))\.\s*(.*)'
df[['NumRoman','Roman','Name']] = df.pop('Date_Title').str.extract(rx)
df = df[['NumRoman','Roman','Name', 'Date', 'Copies']]
>>> df
   NumRoman Roman                   Name  Date  Copies
0   05-21 I     I            Don Quixote  1605     252
1  21-20 IV    IV                Macbeth  1629     987
2  10-12 ML    ML  To Kill a Mockingbird  1960     478
3      12 V     V          Invisible Man  1897     136
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zOVQ5i/2/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+(?:-\d+)?\s*(M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3})))` - Group 1 ("NumRoman"):

  - `\d+(?:-\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `-` and one or more digits
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(M{0,4}(?:C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(?:X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(?:I[XV]|V?I{0,3}))` - Group 2 ("Roman"): see [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399) for explanation
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3 ("Name"): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Note `df.pop('Date_Title')` removes the `Date_Title` column and yields it as input for the `extract` method. `df = df[['NumRoman','Roman','Name', 'Date', 'Copies']]` is necessary if you need to keep the original column order.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there might be a more optimal solution, but this is would be a fast way of solving it:

```
df['Date_Title'] = df['Date_Title'].apply(lambda x: (x.split()[0],x.split()[1],' '.join(x.split()[2:])
```

Or:

```
df['Date_Title'] = (df['Date_Title'].str.split().str[0],
                    df['Date_Title'].str.split().str[1],
                    ' '.join(df['Date_Title'].str.split().str[2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the string split:

```
string = "21-20 IV. Macbeth"
i = string.index(".")  # Finds the first point
date, roman = string[:i].split() # 21-20, IV
title = string[i+2:]  # Macbeth
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.assign(x=df['Date_Title'].str.split('\.').str[0],y=df['Date_Title'].str.extract('(\w+(?=\.))'),z=df['Date_Title'].str.split('\.').str[1:].str.join(','))
```