# how can I remove point numbers: '(i)', '(ii)', '(iii)' in answers with regex from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Suppose, I have a pandas dataframe consisting many rows for product name and columns describing their respective features. And they add some numbering system like 1., 2.,3.,... or a),b),c)....or (i),(ii),(iii),... etc. Now I want to remove them in data frame.

```
df.replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'["(i*)"|i*.|(a-zA-Z).|("("a-zA-z")")]', value=r'')
```

but the code is not working. It deletes all i's from the answers eg. consider becomes consder and I can remove a., b. etc if I give it individually i.e., to_replace=r'[a.|b.|A.|B.] but if the pattern is given, it's not working.

how can I remove '(i)', '(ii)', '(iii)' and '(a)', '(A)', 'a.', 'A.' ranges from A-Z and i for one or more with regex pandas dataframe?

Example

INPUT
(i) The cow has four legs. (ii) The cow eats grass. (iii) Cow gives us milk.

OR

a.The cow has four legs. b.The cow eats grass. c.Cow gives us milk.

OUTPUT
The cow has four legs. The cow eats grass. Cow gives us milk.

Comment: I think you need to use escapes for all the `.` literals, as well as for the literal parentheses. Also, why using `a-zA-Z` instead of the group `[a-zA-Z]`? Have you used a tool like regex101 to experiment with your regex?

Comment: Off the top of my head, a regex like `r'\(i+\)|\(?[a-zA-Z]\)|[0-9]+\.'` should work for examples `1.`, `a)`, `(a)`, and `(i)`

Comment: Perhaps `(?:\(?(?:[vx]?i{1,3}|i?[vx])\)|(?:\(|\b)(?:\d{1,2}|[a-z])[.)]) *`? https://regex101.com/r/6Oyc5Z/2/

Comment: I did not find any lead. So, I have to converting DataFrame into string to get the work done...

import re

string = "a. at what time? i) 8pm, i. 9pm, B. 10pm."
match = re.sub("(a\\.|b\\.|B\\.|i+\\)|i+\\.)","",string)
print (match)

>>>at what time?  8pm,  9pm,  10pm.

how to write it in shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
df.replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'^\(?(?:[ivxlcdm]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)[).]', value='')
```

Input:

```
(i) The cow has four legs.
(ii) The cow eats grass.
(iii) Cow gives us milk.
a.The cow has four legs.
b.The cow eats grass.
c.Cow gives us milk.
1.The cow has four legs.
2.The cow eats grass.
3.Cow gives us milk.
a)The cow has four legs.
b)The cow eats grass.
c)Cow gives us milk.
```

Output:

```
The cow eats grass.
Cow gives us milk.
The cow has four legs.
The cow eats grass.
Cow gives us milk.
The cow has four legs.
The cow eats grass.
Cow gives us milk.
The cow has four legs.
The cow eats grass.
Cow gives us milk.
```

Explanation of the regex `^\(?(?:[ivxlcdm]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)[).]`:

- `^` indicates the start of the string.
- `\(?` matches a zero or one left parenthesis.
- `(?:[ivxlcdm]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)` can be broken down either of:

  - `[ivxlcdm]+` which matches Roman numerals.
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` which matches alphabets.
  - `[0-9]+` which matches digits.
- `[).]` matches a right parenthesis or a dot.

Comment: r'[i]+' removes all i's from the sentence but I want to remove only (i) or (ii..) this pattern.

Comment: It does not. My regex is anchored with `^` and matches only within parens or before `)` or `.`. Have you actually tested?

Answer (score 1):

If there can only be 1 or more times an `i` char (so no roman numerals) you might use:

```
\(?i+\)|\b(?:[A-Za-z]|\d+)\.
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(?i+\)` Match an optional `(`, then 1+ times an `i` char and a `)`
- `|` Or
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z]` Match a single char A-Za-z
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\.` Match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ao5AMF/1/)

If you want to match roman numerals, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression).

Comment: @Nick : thank you...it is a great help for me.

Comment: @souvikdatta Let me say "you are welcome" in the name of Nick and tshiono