# Regex doesnt stop after sign

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have regex like this

```
(.*(?=\sI+)*) (.*)
```

But it doesn't capture groups correctly as I need.

For this example data :

1. Vladimir Goth
2. Langraab II Landgraab
3. Léa Magdalena III Rouault Something
4. Anna Maria Teodora
5. Léa Maria Teodora II

1,2 are only correctly captured.

**So what I need is**

- If there is no I+ is split by first space.
- If after I+ there are other words first gorup should contains all to I+. So, group1 for 3rd example should be Léa Magdalena III
- If after I+ there aren't any other words like in example 5, group1 should be capture to first space.

@Edit
I+ should be replaced by roman numbers

Comment: I feel bad for Henry VIII

Comment: oh.. good point ! yes.Youre right

Comment: Is it in PHP? What is the regex library?

Comment: Just regex from regex101. But i use it in java program

Comment: What kind of Roman number? Any? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405/3832970)?

Comment: I dont think that will be more  than 10 or 20 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support any [Roman numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267399/3832970) you can use

```java
^(\S+(?:.*\b(?=[MDCLXVI])M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b(?= +\S))?) +(.*)
```

If you need to support Roman numbers up to XX (exclusive):

```java
^(\S+(?:.*\b(?=[XVI])X?(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b(?= +\S))?) +(.*)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/V39MJe/7) and [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/V39MJe/6). Replace spaces with `\h` or `\s` in the Java code and double backslashes in the Java string literal.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(` - Group 1 start:

  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespaces
  - `(?:` - a non-capturing group:

    - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
    - `\b` - a word boundary
    - `(?=[MDCLXVI])` - require at least one Roman digit immediately to the right
    - `M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})` - a Roman number pattern
    - `\b` - a word boundary
    - `(?= +\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more spaces and then one non-whitespace right after the current position
  - `)?` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat one or  zero times (it is optional)
- `)` - end of the first group
- `+` - one or more spaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the line.

In Java:

```java
String regex = "^(\\S+(?:.*\\b(?=[MDCLXVI])M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\\b(?=\\h+\\S))?)\\h+(.*)";
// Or
String regex = "^(\\S+(?:.*\\b(?=[XVI])X?(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\\b(?=\\s+\S))?)\\s+(.*)";
```

Comment: Yeap works perfectly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @VANILKA Now, it should work. I thought I managed to make the Roman number pattern match at least one char before, but it appears it could not match `X` number. Now, with the lookahead, it should require at least one Roman digit and it should work fine now.