# JasperReports: Report count start with I,II,III or a,b,c

Tags: jasper-reports

In *JasperReports* report I am looking for "How can I increment a variable using report_count and start with I,II,III... or a,b,c" like this:

```
This is page 1
No Name Add
1  ---- ---
2  ---- ---
3  ---- ---
4  ---- ---
5  ---- ---

This is page 2
No Name Add
6  ---- ---
7  ---- ---
8  ---- ---
9  ---- ---
10 ---- ---
```

and I don't know how can I change all the number 1,2,3... to a,b,c or I,II,III...

```
1 - a    or 1 - I
2 - b       2 - II
3 - c       3 - III    
.....................
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a, b, c, etc. you can take the count variable i = 1, 2, 3 ... and add 96 so that i=97, 98, 99 ... which are the ascii codes for a, b, c,...

You find the ascii codes [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/ascii.html) and then you could put the following statement into a variable to convert to a,b,c,...:

```
java.lang.Character.toString ((char) $V{REPORT_COUNT}+96)
```

Change the evaluation time of the variable to "Report".

Regarding the roman numerals, Java does not have any classes in the standard library, so you have to add a jar-file with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921866/how-do-you-find-a-roman-numeral-equivalent-of-an-integer) class in it.

Comment: thank you for your help, but i looking for jasper report design, Can you descript clear where i can put statement to convert them inside report design???

Comment: I changed the statement. I think you can pretty much paste that statement into the variable expression of a variable.

Comment: it's very useful for my report, one again thank you Johansson.lc

Comment: hi Johansson, i looking for code start with I, II, III, IV, V...but i don't see it in the ascii codes. Can you help me?

Comment: It does not exist as ascii codes.You have to add a jar file for it, as I said above.

Comment: You are very correct. Thanks. However for newbies like me.
 Create a variable, make it java.lang.Character and in variable expression give (char)($V{REPORT_COUNT}+96)) Which gives you a,b,c..