# Numbers to Roman Numbers with php

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, roman-numerals

I need to transform ordinary numbers to Roman numerals with php and I have this code:

```
        <?php

function roman2number($roman){
    $conv = array(
        array("letter" => 'I', "number" => 1),
        array("letter" => 'V', "number" => 5),
        array("letter" => 'X', "number" => 10),
        array("letter" => 'L', "number" => 50),
        array("letter" => 'C', "number" => 100),
        array("letter" => 'D', "number" => 500),
        array("letter" => 'M', "number" => 1000),
        array("letter" => 0, "number" => 0)
    );
    $arabic = 0;
    $state = 0;
    $sidx = 0;
    $len = strlen($roman);

    while ($len >= 0) {
        $i = 0;
        $sidx = $len;

        while ($conv[$i]['number'] > 0) {
            if (strtoupper(@$roman[$sidx]) == $conv[$i]['letter']) {
                if ($state > $conv[$i]['number']) {
                    $arabic -= $conv[$i]['number'];
                } else {
                    $arabic += $conv[$i]['number'];
                    $state = $conv[$i]['number'];
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $len--;
    }

    return($arabic);
}


function number2roman($num,$isUpper=true) {
    $n = intval($num);
    $res = '';

    /*** roman_numerals array ***/
    $roman_numerals = array(
        'M' => 1000,
        'CM' => 900,
        'D' => 500,
        'CD' => 400,
        'C' => 100,
        'XC' => 90,
        'L' => 50,
        'XL' => 40,
        'X' => 10,
        'IX' => 9,
        'V' => 5,
        'IV' => 4,
        'I' => 1
    );

    foreach ($roman_numerals as $roman => $number)
    {
        /*** divide to get matches ***/
        $matches = intval($n / $number);

        /*** assign the roman char * $matches ***/
        $res .= str_repeat($roman, $matches);

        /*** substract from the number ***/
        $n = $n % $number;
    }

    /*** return the res ***/
    if($isUpper) return $res;
    else return strtolower($res);
}

/* TEST */
echo $s=number2roman(6,true);
echo "\n and bacK:\n";
echo roman2number($s);


?>
```

try this way but does not work:

```
echo $s=number2roman((.$row['id'].),true);
echo "\n and bacK:\n";
echo roman2number($s);
```

the problem is that I need to change numbers are readings of my sql database and do not know how to, from and through.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267351/how-can-i-convert-from-integers-to-roman-numerals-using-a-syntax-directed-transl?rq=1

Comment: Oh your title is backwards. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265596/how-to-convert-a-roman-numeral-to-integer-in-php

Comment: [Number To Roman in PHP](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/roman-php-t4948/)

Comment: mkaatman this page is the inverse of my problem!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I found this code here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

Optimized and prettified function:

```
/**
 * @param int $number
 * @return string
 */
function numberToRomanRepresentation($number) {
    $map = array('M' => 1000, 'CM' => 900, 'D' => 500, 'CD' => 400, 'C' => 100, 'XC' => 90, 'L' => 50, 'XL' => 40, 'X' => 10, 'IX' => 9, 'V' => 5, 'IV' => 4, 'I' => 1);
    $returnValue = '';
    while ($number > 0) {
        foreach ($map as $roman => $int) {
            if($number >= $int) {
                $number -= $int;
                $returnValue .= $roman;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: but I need to transform a reading MYSQL and this code does not work:
`echo romanic_number(. $row['id'].);`
I'm sorry, is not handling well the php yet.

Comment: No, the problem is not the function. I suggest you learn how to handle variables within functions and arrays, you need to say ...".echo romanic_number($row_id)."...

Comment: I added the end-tag for php and implemented the $upcase support

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do that

```
<?php 
function ConverToRoman($num){ 
    $n = intval($num); 
    $res = ''; 

    //array of roman numbers
    $romanNumber_Array = array( 
        'M'  => 1000, 
        'CM' => 900, 
        'D'  => 500, 
        'CD' => 400, 
        'C'  => 100, 
        'XC' => 90, 
        'L'  => 50, 
        'XL' => 40, 
        'X'  => 10, 
        'IX' => 9, 
        'V'  => 5, 
        'IV' => 4, 
        'I'  => 1); 

    foreach ($romanNumber_Array as $roman => $number){ 
        //divide to get  matches
        $matches = intval($n / $number); 

        //assign the roman char * $matches
        $res .= str_repeat($roman, $matches); 

        //substract from the number
        $n = $n % $number; 
    } 

    // return the result
    return $res; 
} 

echo ConverToRoman(23); 
?>
```

Comment: This answer can be boiled down a little farther by eliminating single use variables, using type casting instead of a function call, and using a combined assignment operator. https://3v4l.org/LgGaj

Answer (score 5):

You can format integers into Roman numeral symbols with the ICU `intl` library's `NumberFormatter` class by setting the `locale` parameter to `@numbers=roman` with decimal style format:

```php
function intToRomanNumeral(int $num) {
    static $nf = new NumberFormatter('@numbers=roman', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    return $nf->format($num);
}
```

Output examples:

```php
echo intToRomanNumeral(2); // II

echo intToRomanNumeral(5); // V

echo intToRomanNumeral(10); // X

echo intToRomanNumeral(50); // L

echo intToRomanNumeral(57); // LVII
echo intToRomanNumeral(58); // LVIII

echo intToRomanNumeral(100); // C

echo intToRomanNumeral(150); // CL

echo intToRomanNumeral(1000); // M

echo intToRomanNumeral(10000); // ↂ
```

Alternatively, you can use the `MessageFormatter` class, but in my own testing it appears to have significantly lower performance than `NumberFormatter`:

```php
function intToRomanNumeral(int $num) {
    static $nf = new MessageFormatter('@numbers=roman', '{0, number}');
    return $nf->format([$num]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function rome($N){
    $c='IVXLCDM';
    for($a=5,$b=$s='';$N;$b++,$a^=7)
        for($o=$N%$a,$N=$N/$a^0;$o--;$s=$c[$o>2?$b+$N-($N&=-2)+$o=1:$b].$s);
    return $s;
}

// from polish wiki
```

Comment: This seems to work, but warns: `Illegal offset at ''`. I've put `@$c[...` and it seems to be perfect.

Comment: @Vojtěch that turns off error reporting, of course it'll *look* perfect.

Comment: Works with 1, 2, 3 and then crashes on 'A non-numeric value encountered' for $N = 4, tested with PHP 7.3.

Comment: This attempt at codegolf is missing its educational explanation and the snippet itself is not easy to read with the obvious deficit of spaces.

Comment: This snippet generates Errors/Warnings/Notices/Deprecations as of PHP7.4.  https://3v4l.org/P98ul

Comment: There is an illegal offset issue.

Replace

`$o=1:$b].$s);`

with

`$o=1:$b >0 ? $b : 0].$s);`

Answer (score 1):

> CHECKED AND VERIFIED BY PHP UNIT

Make a class having name **RomanNumerials** and add a protected static property as defined:

```
protected static $lookup = [
        1000 => 'M',
        900 => 'CM',
        500 => 'D',
        400 => 'CD',
        100 => 'C',
        90 => 'XC',
        50 => 'L',
        40 => 'XL',
        10 => 'X',
        9 => 'IX',
        5 => 'V',
        4 => 'IV',
        1 => 'I',
    ];
```

then add a method as follows

```
public function output ($number)
    {
        $solution = '';

        foreach(static::$lookup as $limit => $glyph){
            while ($number >= $limit) {
                $solution .= $glyph;
                $number -= $limit;
            }
        }

        return $solution;
    }
```

Comment: I adopted the same, fastest method of all the ones on this topic. Timed with loops from 1 to 20000, the str_repeat method is much slower, and the other 'while' method is slightly slower because of the $map spanning restart and local allocation. I couldn't time the oneliner from Jasiek above as it doesn't work with PHP 7.3 and this is code I won't/can't read/debug.

Answer (score 0):

I improve rome() function of Jasiek

```
function rome2($N)
{
    // support for numbers greater than a thousand
    $ss = '';
    while ($N > 1000) {
        $ss .= 'M';
        $N -= 1000;
    }

    $c = 'IVXLCDM';
    for ($a = 5, $b = 0, $s = ''; $N; $b++, $a ^= 7)
        for ($o = $N % $a, $N = $N / $a ^ 0; $o--; ) {
            $s = $c[$o > 2 ? $b + $N - ($N &= -2) + $o = 1 : $b] . $s;
        }
    return $ss.$s;
}
```

Comment: This unexplained snippet requires explicit int casting to work from PHP7.4 https://3v4l.org/HnMGO

Answer (score 0):

My own function it has the best performance:

```php
function romanNumber($n)
{
    // support for numbers greater than a thousand
    $ret1 = '';
    while ($n >= 1000) {
        $ret1 .= 'M';
        $n -= 1000;
    }

    $ret = '';
    if ($n > 0) {
        $n = (string) $n;
        $l = 'IVXLCDM';
        $j = 0; // goes by roman letters
        for ($i = strlen($n)-1; $i >= 0; --$i) { // goes by decimal number
            switch ($n[$i]) {
                case 0: $s = ''; break;
                case 1: $s = $l[$j]; break;
                case 2: $s = $l[$j].$l[$j]; break;
                case 3: $s = $l[$j].$l[$j].$l[$j]; break;
                case 4: $s = $l[$j].$l[$j+1]; break;
                case 5: $s = $l[$j+1]; break;
                case 6: $s = $l[$j+1].$l[$j]; break;
                case 7: $s = $l[$j+1].$l[$j].$l[$j]; break;
                case 8: $s = $l[$j+1].$l[$j].$l[$j].$l[$j]; break;
                case 9: $s = $l[$j].$l[$j+2]; break;
            }
            $j += 2;
            $ret = $s.$ret;
        }
    }

    return $ret1.$ret;
}
```

Comment: This verbose/inelegant answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

While appreciate the succinct mathematical nested loop approach posted by @user2095686, I agree more with @HaiderLasani's approach of writing the `foreach()` as the outer loop because it never unnecessarily revisits previously processed elements in the translation array. Haider's answer does not explain why this adjustment is ideal.  I've created a [demo](https://3v4l.org/jiVR5) to echo out all of the unnecessary conditional checks that @user2095686's answer makes.  Gone one step further than @Haider's answer, I've written a condition inside of the `while()` loop to break both loops as soon as the modified input integer is reduced to zero.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/96Muo))

```
function numberToRoman(int $integer): string {
    static $conversions = [
        1000 => 'M',
        900 => 'CM',
        500 => 'D',
        400 => 'CD',
        100 => 'C',
        90 => 'XC',
        50 => 'L',
        40 => 'XL',
        10 => 'X',
        9 => 'IX',
        5 => 'V',
        4 => 'IV',
        1 => 'I'
    ];
    $romanString = '';
    foreach ($conversions as $int => $roman) {
        while ($integer >= $int) {
            $integer -= $int;
            $romanString .= $roman;
            if (!$integer) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return $romanString;
}
```

---

If you are not turned off by the style of performing assignment arithmetic inside of a conditional expression, the script can be condensed a little more...

```
foreach ($conversions as $int => $roman) {
    while ($integer >= $int) {
        $romanString .= $roman;
        if (!($integer -= $int)) {
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Check out my solution here https://github.com/frostymarvelous/Whisppa-Libs/blob/master/Misc/Numeralo.php . It works both ways.

```
    <?php
     /**
     * @package    Whisppa
     * @subpackage Misc
     * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT  MIT License
     * @author     Stefan (frostymarvelous) Froelich <sfroelich@gmail.com>
     * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015, Stefan (frostymarvelous) Froelich
     */
    namespace Whisppa\Misc;


    /**
     * This class allows you to convert from Roman numerals to natural numbers and vice versa.
     * I decided to do this as a fun challenge after reading http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Roman-Enumeration
     * Took me about 30 minutes to come up with, research and code the solution.
     * It can convert numbers up to 3,999,999 because I couldn't find any numerals for 5,000,000 above.
     * Due to my inability to get the correct accented characters 5000 above, I resulted to using the pipe (|) to represent accent. 
     */
    class Numeralo
    {
        /**
        * @var string[] A notation map to represent the common Roman numeral values. 
        * @static
        */
        protected static $NOTATION = 
        [
            '|', //one
            '[', //five
            ']', //ten
        ];

        /**
        * @var \ArrayObject[] A map of Roman numerals based on place value. Each item ends with the first numeral in the next place value.
        * @static
        */
        protected static $NUMERALS_BY_PLACE_VALUE =     
        [
            ['I', 'V', 'X',], //ones
            ['X', 'L', 'C',], //tens
            ['C', 'D', 'M',], // hundreds
            ['M', 'V|', 'X|',], //thousands
            ['X|', 'L|', 'C|',], //tens of thousands
            ['C|', 'D|', 'M|',], //hundreds of thousands
            ['M|', '~', '~',], // millions. there are no values for the last two that I could find
        ];

        /**
        * @var string[]  sA map of numbers and their representative Roman numerals in notation format. This map allows us to make any numeral by replacing the the notation with the place value equivalent.    
        * @static
        */
        protected static $NUMBER_TO_NOTATION = 
        [
            '0' => '',
            '1' => '|',
            '2' => '||',
            '3' => '|||',
            '4' => '|[',
            '5' => '[',
            '6' => '[|',
            '7' => '[||',
            '8' => '[|||',
            '9' => '|]',
        ];

        /**
        * @var int[] A map of the major Roman numerals and the number equivalent.
        * @static
        */
        protected static $NUMERALS_TO_NUMBER = 
        [
            'I' => 1,
            'V' => 5,
            'X' => 10,
            'L' => 50,
            'C' => 100,
            'D' => 500,
            'M' => 1000,
            'V|' => 5000,
            'X|' => 10000,
            'L|' => 50000,
            'C|' => 100000,
            'D|' => 500000,
            'M|' => 1000000,
        ];

        /**
        * Converts natural numbers to Roman numerals.
        *
        * @static
        * @param int|string $number a number or numeric string less than 3,999,999
        * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if the provided $number argument is not numeric or greater than 3,999,999.
        * @return string Roman numeral equivalent   
        */
        public static function number_to_numerals($number) {
            if(!is_numeric($number))
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Only numbers allowed');
            if($number > 3999999)
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Number cannot be greater than 3,999,999');


            $numerals = '';
            $number_string = strrev((string) $number);
            $length = strlen($number_string);

            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $char = $number_string[$i];

                $num_map = self::$NUMERALS_BY_PLACE_VALUE[$i];
                $numerals = str_replace(self::$NOTATION, $num_map, self::$NUMBER_TO_NOTATION[$char]) . $numerals;
            }

            return $numerals;   
        }

        /**
        * Converts Roman numerals to natural numbers.
        *
        * @static
        * @param string $numerals the Roman numerals to be converted
        * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if the provided $numerals argument contains invalid characters.
        * @return int the equivalent number
        */
        public static function numerals_to_number($numerals) {
            $number = 0;
            $numeral_string = strrev((string) $numerals);
            $length = strlen($numeral_string);

            $prev_number = false;
            $is_accented = false;

            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $char = $numeral_string[$i];

                if($char == '|') //check if it is an accent character
                {
                    $is_accented = true;
                    continue;//skip this iteration and process it in the next one as the accent applies to the next char
                }
                else if($is_accented)
                {
                    $char .= '|';
                    $is_accented = false;
                }

                //TODO Make a check using maybe regex at the beginning of the method.
                if(!isset(self::$NUMERALS_TO_NUMBER[$char]))
                    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid character '{$char}' in numeral string");


                $num = self::$NUMERALS_TO_NUMBER[$char];

                //this is where the magic happens
                //if the previous number divided by 5 or 10 is equal to the current number, then we subtract eg. 9 = IX. I = 1, X = 10, 10/10 = 1
                if($prev_number)
                {
                    if(($prev_number / 5) == $num || ($prev_number / 10) == $num)
                        $number -= $num;
                    else
                        $number += $num;
                }
                else
                    $number += $num;


                $prev_number = $num;
            }

            return $number;

        }


    }
```